# Extract value from template argument's template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In the following code:

```
template<auto A>
struct S{};

template<template <auto A> class H>
auto foo(){
    return A;
}

auto bar(){
    return foo<S<1>>(); // should return 1
}
```

I would expect it to compile a bar() method that would just return `1`
However I get these errors:

```
<source>: In function 'auto foo()':
<source>:15:12: error: 'A' was not declared in this scope
   15 |     return A;
      |            ^
<source>: In function 'void bar()':
<source>:19:15: error: no matching function for call to 'foo<S<1> >()'
   19 |     foo<S<1>>();
      |               ^
<source>:14:6: note: candidate: 'template<template<auto A> class H> auto foo()'
   14 | auto foo(){
      |      ^~~
<source>:14:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Is there any way to actually get the value A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` doesn't designate something that exists. The parameter to `foo` is a *template*, not a specialization. It's important to make the distinction, because that's why you get a mismatch error for passing `S<1>`, the correct argument to what you've written would be `foo<S>`.

`S<1>` is a specialization, it has the missing bit (the argument) filled in. But `H` is not a specialization, it's the template itself, without an argument. `A` there is nothing but a mnemonic for something *to be filled*, it's not something that's there yet, so you can't use it.

To get at what you want, one would need partial template specialization. That is not applicable to function templates, but we can get around it by forwarding to a member of a class template. Something like this:

```
template<auto A>
struct S{};

template<typename> struct foo_helper;

template<template <auto> class H, auto A>
struct foo_helper<H<A>> {
    static auto run() { return A; }
};

template<class H>
auto foo(){
    return foo_helper<H>::run();
}

auto bar(){
    return foo<S<1>>(); // should return 1
}
```

Now `foo`'s template parameter is a type (not a template). That type is then fed as an argument to the helper, and matched against the template specialization. Since the type has the argument filled in, the specialization extracts it, and returns it.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<template <auto A> class H>
auto foo(){
    return A;
}
```

defines a function that takes a template, not a specialization.  That means you would need to call it like `foo<S>()`, since `S` names a template, not `foo<S<1>>()` as `S<1>` is a specialization.

One thing you can do is change `foo` to

```
template<template <auto> class H, auto A>
auto foo(){
    return A;
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
foo<S, 1>()
```

which then lets foo use the template `S` and have a value (1 in this case) to use with it.

If you want `foo<S<1>>()` to return `1` then you can add a helper function and change `foo` to the following

```
template<template <auto> class T, auto V>
constexpr auto get_value(T<V>)
{
    return V;
}

template<typename T>
auto foo(){
    return get_value(T{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<auto A_val>
struct S {
    static constexpr auto A = A_val;
    static constexpr auto v = 2;
};


template<class H>
auto foo(){
    return H::A;
}

auto bar(){
    return foo<S<1>>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << bar() << std::endl;  // Prints "1"
    return 0;
}
```